# Props and Data in Vue.js components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a [very simple DM screen](http://thatredbloke.com/campaign/) for encounters and monsters for D&D.

What I'm trying to do is set up a way to add an encounter, and then set up monsters whose stats will automatically get rolled when adding them.

I've got two components, `encounter` and `monster`, and an JSON object with the monster data set up in (`monster_data`). The idea being the user clicks "Add Monster" then selects what monster to add and the stats would get rolled.

I'm struggling to understand the difference (and quite frankly the point) of having both props and data.

I've read the documentation several times and from what I can understand a prop is a way for a parent (encounter) to pass data down to the child (monster), therefore if I push a new monster into the encounter it renders the properties I passed to it. But I can't mutate those properties, if I wanted to set what type of monster that monster was I can't do that via the props.

Data is just an arbitrary value related to the component. In the examples in the documentation the counter on the button isn't passed as a property. But can be manipulated through functions and displayed.

My question is should I be adding monsters/encounters as data rather than props and if so how? I'm really struggling with this concept and if my approach is completely wrong I'm probably just going to abandon Vue and go back to DOM manipulation.

As requested a cut down [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redreddington/o35qjygz/1/) of my code. The issue being I want to pass value selected from the edit dialog to the monster prop.

Comment: It's about scoping. Data is local to the current vue component. Props are inherited from parent vue components that implement the current vue component. You should show some code. No-one can really submit a meaningful answer for you without it because the answer to the question of what you should do depends on how you've structured your app. Best place for that is on codesandbox.io

Comment: If you want to mutate, then you should be using vuex

Comment: Having read your question a few times my opinion is that you're trying to dive into the deep end of vue too quickly. Vue is not an imperative syntax, so requires a completely different way of thinking than DOM manipulators like jQuery. It takes a while to grok that. There's no short cut. You have to decide whether you want to build an app quickly with your existing knowledge, or whether you want to embark on the journey of learning a new skill-set.

Comment: You should probably look into [Dynamic Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Comment: But don't let the above discourage you. Vue is worth it! I promise.

Comment: Here's a starting point that may help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/811yr1vmx8

Comment: @geoidesic added a codepen to the original description. Yes I accept I am probably diving into the deep end. I'm trying to learn how to use Vue.js but find it extremely frustrating. I don't know whether it's because I'm too used to jQuery like you say and it's a different mindset but I can't find any tutorials that explain that mindset.

Comment: Unfortunately the codepen doesn't really help because it's non-functional. Clicking in the UI just does weird things. Also the whole question of code design also depends on your back-end. It's one thing getting your view model to update based on user-entry, it's another thing getting your back-end to update. So it's not clear what the problem constraints are from your question. it may be that you're asking the wrong question. In other words "updating the prop" is definitely not the right solution but until we have a clearer idea of what you're trying to achieve we won't know.

Comment: Let me put it this way... you're rolling stats for the monster. Fine. Now what do you want to do with those stats? (and don't say "update the props"!)

Comment: Display them in the monster component. So if a user picks a "Bandit" the component will display "Bandit" and the rolled HP next to it. I can do if I set these in the addMonster method within the encounter component, but ideally I'd want to be able to add and then select the type of monster. Would a JS fiddle work?

Comment: JsFiddle is fine. But try include even more simplified code that illustrates what you're trying to do. Your codepen example includes all sorts of function that aren't being called and some calls to functions which don't exist. It's a bit of a mess! :)

Comment: So we need working HP rolling function. As well as your list of monsters and any associated attributes.. Also explain what you mean by "ideally I'd want to be able to add and then select the type of monster".. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Do you mean that once a monster is added, it should be then available in the list of selectable monsters?

Comment: Looking at your page source it seems you are mixing jQuery and Vue. Ouch!

Comment: @geoidesic Well only because I'm used to jQuery but I haven't used it within my app, I don't think? No. When you add a monster to an encounter, it has no data. I have a separate variable called `monster_data` which contains all of the data about the possible monsters. I want to be able to select from the edit dialog which type of monster and pull through the data from `monster_data` into the monster component. Now I might be misunderstanding the point of components but I thought it was to have repeatable Vue instances with their own data and template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182195/discussion-between-redreddington-and-geoidesic).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand about your use case, Here is a simple example may help.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1kngqhe/)

```
Vue.component('encounter', {
    props: ['encounter'], 
    template: '#encounter-template',
    methods: {
        addMonster: function() {
            var monster = {};
            this.encounter.monsters.push(monster);
        },
        onMonsterUpdate (updatedItem, i) {
            this.encounter.monsters.splice(i, 1, updatedItem);
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('monster', {
    template: '#monster-template',
    props: ['monster'], 
    data: function() {
        var data = {
            dialogVisible: false,
            monsterData: monster_data,
            selectedValue: this.monster.slug
        }

        return data;
    },
    methods: {
        toggleDialog: function() {
            if (this.dialogVisible) {
                this.dialogVisible = false;
            } else {
                this.dialogVisible = true;
            }
        },
        onSelected(e) {
          let selectedMonster = this.monsterData.filter(it => it.slug === e.target.value)[0];
          this.$emit('monsterUpdate', selectedMonster)
        }
    },
    updated: function() {
        console.log(this.monster);
    }
});
```